# Distance matrices calculation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, distance

I am programming a wind farm in Matlab, where I need to calculate distances from a line having angle Alpha and passing through point(x,y) for each point (x2,y2)in plane.

Like in image I have uploaded, I need to calculate 2D-matrices for distance s[m,n] and r[m,n].

[image]

My code so far:

```
for I=1:1:2000
    xquery=I;

    for J=1:1:2000
        yquery=J;  %Yquery point from -999 tp 1001

        if (xquery-xcen1<0)
        Raddist1(I,J)=0;        %Radial distance from query point 

        Axialdis(I,J)=0;        %Axial distance from query point

        %q=q+1;
        elseif m1==0                    %If line is parallel to x-axis
                m2=0;  
                a1=xquery;              %X-coordinate equals query point
                b1=intercept1;          %Y-coordinate equals Y-axis intercept as slope m=0 for horizontal line.

                linex(I,J)=a1;          %Storing X value of intersection between perpendicular line
                liney(I,J)=b1;

                line(linex,liney);
                dist1=(a1-xquery)^2+(b1-yquery)^2;  

                Raddist1(I,J)=sqrt(dist1);
                %yy12=m2*x+interc12;             %Equation of line passing through query point and 90 degree to centerline of WT

                Axialdis1(I,J)=sqrt((a1-xcen1)^2+(b1-ycen1)^2);
                g=g+1;

        else
            h=h+1;

                m2=(-1/m1);
                interc12=-(m2*xquery)+yquery;   % y=mx+c equation

                a1=(interc12-intercept1)/ (m1-m2);         %intersection X-coordinate of two line
                b1=m2*a1+interc12;                      %intersection Y-coordinate of two line


                linex(I,J)=a1;
                liney(I,J)=b1;

                dist=(a1-xquery)^2+(b1-yquery)^2;                
                Raddist1(I,J)=sqrt(dist);

                yy12=m2*x+interc12;             %Equation of line passing through query point and 90 degree to centerline of WT

                Axialdis1(I,J)=sqrt((a1-xcen1)^2+(b1-ycen1)^2);
   end
end
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? We're here to help you with code that you may be having issues with, not to write code from scratch for you.

Comment: Yes I have code,here i am sending it.

Comment: @Suever
yes I made a program. But its too slow as I need it to re-run for 30 (xcen,ycen) point comparing with (2000,2000) point matrix.